# Node.JS single socket, multiple events (uploads)

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, socket.io, jquery-file-upload

I'm developing an upload tracker (progress bar, etc).

So for my front-end I use jQuery File upload. 
Back-end upload is done using separate workers and there I use Redis pub/sub.
So to connect front and back-ends I use Node.JS (socket.io).

jQuery file upload has a "`done`" callback function that denotes reaching our file to the server.

This works absolutely fine for a single file.

Problem arises when I try upload 2+ files simultaneously. 
"done" callback function is getting attached to socket listeners 2+ times (correct me if I'm wrong) and as an output I get something like this:

```
579 " - progress: " 8.333333333333334
580 " - progress: " 8.333333333333334 
579 " - progress: " 16.666666666666668 
580 " - progress: " 16.666666666666668 
579 " - progress: " 25 
580 " - progress: " 25
....
579 " -> upload is finished!" 
580 " -> upload is finished!"
```

That was an example of uploading 2 files. Which doesn't make any sense at all, because they can only be processed one after another.

So it should look like this:

```
579 " - progress: " 8.333333333333334
579 " - progress: " 16.666666666666668 
579 " - progress: " 25
....

579 " -> upload is finished!"
580 " - progress: " 8.333333333333334
580 " - progress: " 16.666666666666668
....
580 " -> upload is finished!"
```

Node.js server-side works totally fine.
This is a log from it:

```
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-579
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-579
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-579
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-579
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-579
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-579
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-579
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-579
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-579
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-579
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-579
RECEIVED  done  FROM  upload-579
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-580
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-580
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-580
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-580
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-580
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-580
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-580
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-580
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-580
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-580
RECEIVED  progress  FROM  upload-580
RECEIVED  done  FROM  upload-580
```

It received messages from Redis channel and emits appropriate messages to the client side.
I think problem lies somewhere on the client side, but I cannot figure out how to modify the code there to get what I want.
Can something be done to separate them from each other?

P.S

Comment: Why do you assume that the uploads can't happen concurrently?

Comment: There is only one worker that processes the upload. 
So it is absolutely NOT possible. 
Also, see the log I provided.

Comment: One Node worker or one Redis worker? Can you also show the Node.js code please?

Comment: One delayed_job worker.
Included node.js code

Comment: So where is the actual uploading going on?

Comment: Why would it matter? It is just a single-threaded worker. And it cannot do them simultaneously, thats for certain. 
And Node.JS code runs fine. But the client-side is NOT correct somewhere. I don't know where.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61548/discussion-between-tom-erik-stower-and-dmitri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket event callback on the client-side will fire for any emit messages from Node.js. That's why you are seeing duplicate log messages. Either send additional data in the socket message, or attach unique events.